# ArrayList is unexpectedly emptied when Windows Form Closes?

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm creating a PowerShell function for searching users in AD using a GUI.  The function will ShowDialog() a Windows form for the user to conduct their search, then when the user clicks OK the form closes and function will return an ArrayList containing the AD users they selected.

Everything is working right up until after the form closes.  After the form closes, my ArrayList suddenly has a count of 0 instead of containing the AD users they selected.

I can't understand why the ArrayList ($alRetrievedSelection) is getting emptied.  I literally only have a single line of code that ever modifies this ArrayList.  Everything else is just a Write-Warning for my own debug purposes.

```
#This function returns an arraylist that contains the items selected by the user
function Retrieve-DataGridSelection{...}

#Fake sample data
$array = "Item 1","Item 2","Item 3","Item 4"
$arraylist = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList(,$array)

#Create the basic form
$frmWindow = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

#Create the OK button
$btnOK = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$btnOK.Add_Click({
    $alRetrievedSelection = Retrieve-DataGridSelection -dgDataGridView $datagrid
    #This warning always shows the correct Count
    Write-Warning("Received from Retrieve-DataGridSelection: " + $alRetrievedSelection.Count)
})
$frmWindow.Controls.Add($btnOK)

#Create the datagrid where users will select rows
$datagrid = New-object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$datagrid.DataSource = $arraylist
$frmWindow.Controls.Add($datagrid)

#Give focus to the form
$frmWindow.Add_Shown({$frmWindow.Activate()})

#Display the form on the screen
$frmWindow.ShowDialog()

#This warning keeps telling me the Count is 0 when it should not be
Write-Warning("After the form closes: " + $alRetrievedSelection.Count)
```

Comment: You posted *a lot* of irrelevant code. Couldn't you simplify it, while still showing your problem?

Comment: Sorry about that, I took some time and trimmed it down a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This due to scoping rules of PS. From `Get-Help about_Scopes`:

> [I]tems that you create and change
>   in the child scope do not affect the parent scope, unless you explicitly
>   specify the scope when you create the items.

That means that when you set the variable in the `Click` handler script block (equivalent of C# lambda), you set it only in the local scope of that block, not the global scope.

To set the variable in the global scope, use the `global` scope modifier:

```
$global:alRetrievedSelection = Retrieve-DataGridSelection …
```

Comment: Weird that it works.  I had already ruled out scoping as the cause of the problem, and let me explain why.  I tried:  `$global:alRetrievedSelection = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList` outside the Click handler script block, and it didn't work.  Why?  Is the Click handler not a "child scope"?

Comment: @JLA Read the quote carefully. You can't set a variable from the global scope in the local scope (unless you use `global`), it doesn't matter whether the variable has some value in the global scope.

Comment: So even though the variable was created in the parent scope, it is read-only within the child scopes?  Sorry for being difficult on this!  I am obviously scope-challenged :)

Comment: @JLA Kind of. You can read the variable from the parent scope, but if you try writing to it, you are actually writing to a different variable (with the same name) in the local scope.